# i want the envId and goes to another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead align="center">
    <tr class="success">
            <td>Env-Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Type</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <c:forEach var="env" items="${envList}">
        <tr align="center" class="active" id="commonTr">
            <td>${env.envId}</td>
            <td>${env.envname}</td>
            <td>${env.envtype}</td>
            <td>${env.envdesc}</td>
            <td><a href="" onClick="selectId(this, '${env.envId}');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
            <td><a href="" onClick="getPageDelRequest(this, '${env.envname}');" data-url="deleteEnv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
            </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This is my js code.....

```
function selectId(val) {
    alert('efeeerf' + val.value);

    window.location="editEnv?envId="+val.value;
 }
```

When I click on edit it alert efeeerfundefined. How would I get rid of it?

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your function is:

```
    function selectId(val) {
        alert('efeeerf' + val.value);

        window.location="editEnv?envId="+val.value;
    }
```

And your html

```
    <a href="" onClick="selectId(this, '${env.envId}');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
```

`val` here is `a` html tag and it doesn't have `value` properties so you get undefined error. One more thing, you pass `'${env.envId}'`, that means you pass a string to your function and not an object so It doesn't have `value` property too

If you can change your js function you may try

```
    function selectId(obj, envId) {
        alert('efeeerf' + envId);

        window.location="editEnv?envId=" + envId;
    }
```